# is it possible to create database schema using spring boot with JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, postgresql-9.3

is it possible to create database  schema using spring boot with JPA in postgresql through java coding? like we are creating tables using spring boot with JPA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do. Please refer the Spring Documentation.

[Database Initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)